# Stop a bitwise-or in \emph from becoming a dash

Tags: emphasis

I want to use a "`|`" in my `\emph{}`, like `\emph{"Yes"|"No"}`, but it changes the `|` to a `--`.

How do I stop this from happening?

Comment: `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. However a slanted bar doesn't seem the best choice.

Comment: If you don't mind about badly spaced words, you can substitute `|` with `\textbar`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` you don't have the problem with the bizarre output. However the result is not beautiful. I'll show it together with a `\textor` command that seems better.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\DeclareRobustCommand\textor{%
  \ifdim\fontdimen1\font>0pt % test if the current font is slanted
    \/$\,|$% it is
  \else
    $\,|\,$% it isn't
  \fi}
\begin{document}
\emph{``Yes''|``No''}

\emph{``Yes''\textor``No''}

``Yes''\textor``No''
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I left out the fontenc package as even without using the first method, all the quotes look weird. Thanks for this solution works great!